# Art of writing poems?

Tags: poetry

What are the paramount factors on which every poem depends? What are the things must for a poem to consist?
Despite its source and poet

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE *Vimath*! The goal of StackExchange is to provide a database with concrete questions that have concrete answers that will be able to help a wide variety of people. Critiques would surely help you personally, but there is no value for a bigger audience in the review itself, which is why they are off-topic. Therefore I am voting to put your question temporarily on hold until you [edit] it in such a way that there is a question that aligns with our guidelines. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: I retracted my vote to temporarily put this question on hold. Thanks for the edit! (We have some rules that are difficult for beginners. If you have questions don't hesitate to ask, for example on [meta] or simply by notifying a user in a comment by writing an "@" in front of their username. It even autocompletes.)

Answer (score 1):

A poem that attempts a certain established form must follow the principles of that form, but there are no rules for a *poem in general*.

[Poetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poetry) may

- [rhyme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhyme)
- have a (certain) [metre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metre_(poetry))
- employ [figures of speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech)

but it doesn't have to.

Poems can be [only one letter long](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/how-short-can-a-poem-be-until-it-can-no-longer-be-a-poem), use [visual](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_poetry), [haptic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haptic_poetry), or [material](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_poetry) elements, and poetry can even be [unreadable to humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_poetry), as Genco Gulan's QR code poem.

**Poetry is whatever a poet indends to be poetry.**

Comment: I personally write poems to reflect my life's experiences. How I can make it more attractive and equally understandable for the audience......what role do they play then(the audience) if poetry is whatever a poet intends to be poetry.

Comment: @Vimath That is a different question than the one you have asked here. Maybe you want to open another question that asks about how to make your poetry more understandable and accessible to your readers?

Comment: Pardon but I wanted to ask whether audience plays a part in poetry ......if yes, then should writer consider their feelings while writing poems....if yes then he may not be able to express properly.....

Comment: @Vimath Just ask a new question asking whether audience plays a part in poetry.